# Getting Odd numbers in a array?

Tags: c, cs50

I am begginer,I am faced with a challenge to take few numbers and multiply the odd numbers in them to apply the lunhs alogrithm.

Ex- If user inputs 100034341341313413941391341393413.
Is there any way I can take this input and specifically filter out the numbers in the odd places and even places and add them ?

Please just show me the way or how I can get it the number in a array and approach it.The rest i'll figure out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you going to input such a large number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last digit is always odd so start from there. To get last digit you can use Modulo Operator (`%`) which gives you remainder of a division. If you divide a number by `10` you get your number's very right digit. After that divide your number by 10 (not modulo) to remove right digit. Loop this process until you get 0.

```c
int x = 72;
int last_digit = 72 % 10; // returns 2
int x = x / 10; // its 7.2 but its an int so x will be 7
```

Other approaches can be found in [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-sum-of-digits-of-a-number-at-even-and-odd-places/).

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void getSum(int n) {

    // If n is odd then the last digit
    // will be odd positioned
    int isOdd = (n % 2 == 1) ? 1 : 0;

    // To store the respective sums
    int sumOdd = 0;
    int sumEven = 0;

    // While there are digits left process
    while (n != 0) {

        // If current digit is odd positioned
        if (isOdd)
            sumOdd += n % 10;

        // Even positioned digit
        else
            sumEven += n % 10;

        // Invert state
        isOdd = !isOdd;

        // Remove last digit
        n /= 10;
    }

    printf("Sum odd = %d\n", sumOdd);
    printf("Sum even = %d\n", sumEven);
}
```

Comment: For example:user inputs 10 number digits.How can that be set as the array size ? 
Thanks a lot for your prompt answer.Learning a lot !

Comment: Put a counter in `while` loop to count digits. When it comes to declaring array, using fixed size arrays not too good for it because your digit count can be vary. You can use dynamically allocated array(`malloc()`) for it. (In some compilers you can't define numbers that doesn't know at compile time.)

Comment: On SO it is not encouraged to provide code-only answers or links to external resources. You might improve by adding explanation what you are doing. Additionally you should provide an answer that actually matches the language from the question. That is tagged as C while your code only compiles with a C++ compiler.

Comment: `if (isOdd)` That doesn't seem to be useful both on C and C++.

Comment: `100034341341313413941391341393413` doesn't look like it would fit in `int`

Comment: What data type will this number fit in?

Comment: Looks like a string would be more suitable. Or even just a single character in case you read and sum up each digit directly while reading. No need to store.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate LUHN algorithm on a string is always far better than doing it with an `int` variable, as the integer has a limited amount of memory to represent the numbers normally managed in a credit card.  Normally credit card numbers are 20 digits long (but they can grow up to 24 or more), while `long` integers reach roughly 18 digits and make it impossible to get.

In addition to what was exposed above, the LUHN algorithm can be simulated as a DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton) that can be easily implemented with a table and a loop, as follows:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const static char luhn_tab[][10] = {
    { 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 }, /* state 0, accepting state */
    { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10 }, /*   ''  1 */
    { 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11 },
    { 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12 },
    { 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13 },
    { 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 }, /*   ''  5 */
    { 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 },
    { 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 },
    { 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17 },
    { 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 }, /*   ''  9 */
    {  0,  2,  4,  6,  8,  1,  3,  5,  7,  9 }, /* state 10, accepting state */
    {  1,  3,  5,  7,  9,  2,  4,  6,  8,  0 },
    {  2,  4,  6,  8,  0,  3,  5,  7,  9,  1 },
    {  3,  5,  7,  9,  1,  4,  6,  8,  0,  2 },
    {  4,  6,  8,  0,  2,  5,  7,  9,  1,  3 },
    {  5,  7,  9,  1,  3,  6,  8,  0,  2,  4 },
    {  6,  8,  0,  2,  4,  7,  9,  1,  3,  5 },
    {  7,  9,  1,  3,  5,  8,  0,  2,  4,  6 },
    {  8,  0,  2,  4,  6,  9,  1,  3,  5,  7 },
    {  9,  1,  3,  5,  7,  0,  2,  4,  6,  8 },
};

/* as the number of states is less than 32, we can use the bits of
 * an integer to mark which states are accepting states and which aren't */
const static int accepting = (1 << 0) | (1 << 10);

int luhn_ok(char *s, size_t s_len)
{
    s += s_len; /* point to the string end */
    char st = 0; /* automaton state, initially zero */
    while (s_len--) {
        if (isdigit(*--s)) {
            /* operate only on digits, skipping nondigits */
            st = luhn_tab[st][*s - '0'];
        }
    }
    /* accepting state only if final state is one of the marked
     * bits in accepting */
    return ((1 << st) & accepting) != 0;
} /* luhn_ok */

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("luhn_ok(\"%s\") == %s\n",
                argv[i],
                luhn_ok(argv[i],
                        strlen(argv[i]))
                    ? "Good" 
                    : "Bad");
    }
} /* main */
```

As you see, the only difficulty lies in that I have to scan the string of digits from the rigth, instead of doing it from the left (to tie us to the odd/even position in the string)  This can also be done from the left (I mean, with an automaton), but the automaton table grows up to 100 states (because we don't know if we start in an odd/even position from the left digit), instead of 20 of the table above  /well, I have not minimized the table, but I think I will not get a table simpler than 100 states)  Above, the state represents the expected LUHN remainder after processing the digits of the string, with 10 added if we are in an odd position or even.  You will easily see that this matches the algorithm you have been given.

```
$ luhn "100034341341313413941391341393413" 12345678903
luhn_ok("100034341341313413941391341393413") == Bad
luhn_ok("12345678903") == Good
$ _
```

#### Note:

I have computed the [100 states table to allow computing the LUHN algorithm left to right](https://github.com/mojadita/luhn), but finally I considered it cumbersome to add it here, as it adds no advantage to the computing (it is only interesting if you don't know in advance how long your string of digits will be, or if you are involved in a parsing algorithm that requires left to right parsing)  If someone is interested, please ask for it in the comments, and I'll add it.